# Does Jack3d Micro increase Metabolism?

Tags: weight-loss, diet, cardio, supplements

I am over weight and I need to lose weight.

I am planning to hit back to Gym soon and work hard on the Cardio. Of course Diet is really important and I need to be careful what I am eating.

I am looking for a supplement (for pre-workout) to help to increase my metabolism and extra energy to lose weight faster when I am on the Cardio.

I have been researching through the Internet and it seem Jack3d Micro can do the job?

Comment: In addition to using banned ingredients, it also contains ingredients which would cause you to fail a USADA level drug testing. Your best bet is going to be real food and consistent effort, not a short term quickie fix of any kind.

Comment: NOTE: Jack3d Micro is USP Lab's offering _after_ removing the DMAA product from the shelves and voluntarily destroying their current stock at the time. http://www.jack3dmicro.org/ingredients

Comment: @BerinLoritsch - Hard to say. It's not on the USADA 411 list yet, but they hide ingredients in their proprietary ENOS and CNS portions of the label. They do have some members of the hydroxy- class, which have a few counterparts on the 411. Currently not listed, which does not necessarily mean safe.

Comment: My only point is that unless you _can_ say without a doubt, saying that they use banned ingredients without qualification might not be considered libel (due to lack of proof).  Your second statement is indeed a very fair assessment, and is warranted.

Answer (score 3):

Be very cautious. The key chemical of Jack3d was DMAA, which was [pulled off of the market when it was marketed as a nasal decongestant due to "headaches, tremors, and increased blood pressure"](http://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/dmaa-efficacious-but-is-it-safe/). The chemical structure is similar to amphetamines and. And no, they don't extract it from geraniums. At the level of the compound in geraniums, they'd have to crush a few tons of geraniums for each dose. Like many "natural" supplements, it's a chemical that's dodging around the rules the FDA has established to keep people from marketing drugs as supplements. The FDA has a website specifically warning of [the dangers of Jack3d](http://www.fda.gov/Food/DietarySupplements/QADietarySupplements/ucm346576.htm).

As `Berin Loritsch` has pointed out, *Jack3d Micro* is supposed to be a reformulated mix that lacks the dangerous chemicals, but I'd still advise caution. If I get food poisoning at a restaurant, the food might be perfectly fine the next time I go there because it was a one-off, but it could also be that there's something wrong systematically, such that the problem will return in a different way.

I'll agree with Kneel Before ZOD that your primary steps will be slowly increasing your amount of exercise and eating a better diet. I disagree with him on green tea extract [which has consistently shown no effect in reputable studies](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19906797?dopt=Abstract). In general, any time someone claims that there's one substance that helps you lose weight, they're generally talking through their hat unless they're discussing amphetamines which have their usual issues (you know, addiction, high blood pressure, sudden death). Diet and exercise are the only proven methods short of radical surgery.

Answer (score 2):

First, ***congratulations for recognizing that you need to lose weight.*** You've taken the first step. 
 
Second, *don't plan to "hit back to gym soon and work hard on the cardio."* That doesn't usually work. If you can go for a walk right now, go for a 30 mins walk. If not, perform 10 squats. If possible, do jumping jacks *(modify it if you cannot lift yourself)* for 15 seconds. That's not planning; that's doing. Countless people plan to lose weight without actually doing something. Don't waste time planning; jump in and start doing something. 
 
Third, diet is an integral part and I'm glad you realize that. Starting tomorrow *(or today, depending on the time)* start your day with a protein-filled and fiber-filled breakfast. Make them low calories as best as possible; incorporate vegetables, lean meat, fruits, and nuts in your daily intake *(both as food and snack)*. 
 
Fourth, the most effective metabolism-increasing supplements contain **green tea.** So, rather than seeking a particular brand, seek supplements that contain green tea. They naturally increase your metabolism and provide you with the energy to be more active. 
 
Fifth, take **supplements that are rich in Vitamins B-complex.** The vitamins naturally increase your energy level and allow you to be more active. You can also just go to a pharmacy and ask them to give you supplements that increase your energy level; they should provide you with supplements that have Vitamins B along with other nutrients. 
 
In summary, to lose weight: eat right, exercise often *(and be active)*, and take the right supplements *(not a requirement, but supplements provide many nutrients that aren't accessible through food alone)*. 
 
Welcome on your new journey to sculpt your body. Stay in touch for motivation, encouragement, and information on how others are faring on this wonderful journey. 
 
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @Kneel-Before-ZOD - That is extremely helpful, much appreciated taking your time you answer. Could you give me example of which brand you recommend contain green tea?

Comment: Formutech Nutrition Level II contain green tea it seem.

Comment: Other one I have found is HYDROXYCUT HARDCORE ELITE POWDER that contain green tea.. which one do you suggest?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back I'll not suggest any brand because I don't want you to focus on the wrong thing. Go to Walmart *(its equivalent or a pharmacy in your area)* , look for a brand that contains the mentioned ingredient; it would be nice if it's a popular brand too, but don't focus on that. Your goal should be **to have energy to be more active** . Any reputable brand will do that for you. Moreover, I don't want you dependent on a particular brand and be unable to exercise because you haven't taken your daily supplement. After taking it consistently for a while, reduce your intake.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back By reducing your intake and maintaining your energy level, you allow your body to naturally increase its energy level *(and reduce its dependency on pills)* .